# Create Sitemap of Production Links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The sitemap is storing links I made in development. How can the links be taken from production?

**`$ rake sitemap:create`**

```
In '/Users/galli01anthony/Dropbox/LiveToChallenge/public/sitemaps/':
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                         133 links /    2.09 KB
Sitemap stats: 133 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m02s

Pinging with URL 'http://www.livetochallenge.com/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

The default_host is correct, but it is showing links like http://www.livetochallenge.com/challenges/19-test, which doesn't exist in production. http://0.0.0.0:3000/challenges/19-test only exists in development.

**sitemap.rb**

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'http://www.livetochallenge.com/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'public/sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add posts_path, changefreq: 'daily'
  add challenges_path, changefreq: 'daily'
  add inspirations_path, changefreq: 'weekly'
  add users_path, changefreq: 'weekly'
  add activities_path, changefreq: 'weekly'
  add about_path, changefreq: 'monthly'
  Post.find_each do |f|
    add post_path(f.slug), lastmod: f.updated_at
  end
  Challenge.find_each do |f|
    add challenge_path(f), lastmod: f.updated_at
  end
  Inspiration.find_each do |f|
    add inspiration_path(f), lastmod: f.updated_at
  end
  User.find_each do |f|
    add user_path(f), lastmod: f.updated_at
  end
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines
```

Comment: are you sure that you have deleted the old sitemap.xml.gz file before re-running `$ rake sitemap:create` in production mode?

Comment: I deleted the files manually. Then reran `rake sitemap:create` to the same result @MuteMinute

Comment: where is `19-test` coming from? Is that a parameter for a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running the rake task in your development environment so it's pulling records from your dev database. Make sure you're ENV is set to the production environment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sitemap:create` and that you're able to connect to your production database.

Comment: Thanks so much! Us Anthony's gotta stick together. It's a harsh world out there ;)